# What is the relation between business processes, workflows and activities?

Tags: workflow, business-process-management

I googled the above question in many forms and I could not find any comprehensible answer. Can someone give a real life example that explains the difference between a business process and a workflow ? and how each one is connected to activities. 
This diagram was supposed to help but to be honest, it confused me even more. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Questions like this aren't the core purpose of Stack Overflow, so probably you'll get a few flags. But I'll try to give a short answer.

Like many other notions in computing, these two terms, business process and workflow, aren't precisely defined, at least not in a way that is generally understood and accepted. So each author, tool vendor, and the like, use them at their pleasure. For most practical cases, they are interchangeable. BPMN, for example, has "business process" in its name, but many "workflow" engines do nothing else than implement BPMN.

A diagram like the one you got isn't meaningful without a clear explanation of the meaning of its constructs. That's the duty of its author and can't be done by you or me without knowing his intentions.

If anything, the term "workflow" could be more specific than "business process". The workflow means the concrete sequence of actions, like "customer fills order, then vendor calculates delivery data, then warehouse personell fetches products,...". Business process can, depending on the context, also be used for more abstract ideas, like "product design, customer acquisition, order processing" that are not directly related in the everyday work organization.